# Running the powershell command with a different user in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, wmi, impersonation

I have a windows application that I wrote on VS C#, I run the following powershell command when Button3 is pressed,

When I right-click on the Windows application and select run as admin (I enter a different authorized user information), the command works perfectly.

But when I run it with a normal standard user (without permission to run PowerShell) I get an error,

Can I embed the authorized username and password into the application without right-clicking on the application and running it with admin?
​

```
    private void button3_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    
        string command = string.Concat(@"$wmi = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem -computer ", txb_pc.Text.Trim(), "\n", "$LBTime = $wmi.ConvertToDateTime($wmi.Lastbootuptime)","\n", "[TimeSpan]$uptime = New-TimeSpan $LBTime $(get-date)","\n", "\"$($uptime.days) Gun $($uptime.hours) Saat $($uptime.minutes) Dakika\"");


        using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
        {
           
            powerShell.AddScript(command);
            powerShell.AddCommand("Out-String");
            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShell.Invoke();
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (PSObject pSObject in PSOutput)
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(pSObject.ToString());
           txb_islemmonitoru.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
        }


      
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to leverage [JEA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/jea/overview?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: You are mising the impersonation option : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1#-impersonation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very happy, I solved my problem.

With the guidance of my brother "jdweng", I researched various articles and solved my problem using the following method,

I'm sharing it to help others, we can close the topic.

If there is a need to pass specific credentials to Get-WmiObject in order to gather information from remote machine, here is how you can do it:

```
$LAdmin = "DOMAIN\Administrator"
$LPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password!" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $LAdmin, $LPassword


Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computername -Class Win32_VideoController -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Credential $Credentials
```

Comment: To close topic please accept your answer to your question if this is good for you.

Comment: To add to @MarkSchultheiss' comment: [Self-answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) can be accepted after 48 hours have passed.